# How do I present text vertically in a JLabel ? (Java 1.6)

Tags: java, jlabel

I'm looking to have text display vertically, first letter at the bottom, last letter at the top, within a JLabel.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this page: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/VerticalLabelUI.htm when I needed to do that.

I don't know if you want the letters 'standing' on each other or all rotated on their side.

```
/*
 * The contents of this file are subject to the Sapient Public License
 * Version 1.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
 * http://carbon.sf.net/License.html.
 *
 * Software distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" basis,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for
 * the specific language governing rights and limitations under the License.
 *
 * The Original Code is The Carbon Component Framework.
 *
 * The Initial Developer of the Original Code is Sapient Corporation
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2003 Sapient Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
 */


import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLabelUI;

/**
 * This is the template for Classes.
 *
 *
 * @since carbon 1.0
 * @author Greg Hinkle, January 2002
 * @version $Revision: 1.4 $($Author: dvoet $ / $Date: 2003/05/05 21:21:27 $)
 * @copyright 2002 Sapient
 */

public class VerticalLabelUI extends BasicLabelUI {
    static {
        labelUI = new VerticalLabelUI(false);
    }

    protected boolean clockwise;


    public VerticalLabelUI(boolean clockwise) {
        super();
        this.clockwise = clockwise;
    }


    public Dimension getPreferredSize(JComponent c) {
        Dimension dim = super.getPreferredSize(c);
        return new Dimension( dim.height, dim.width );
    }

    private static Rectangle paintIconR = new Rectangle();
    private static Rectangle paintTextR = new Rectangle();
    private static Rectangle paintViewR = new Rectangle();
    private static Insets paintViewInsets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);

    public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {

        JLabel label = (JLabel)c;
        String text = label.getText();
        Icon icon = (label.isEnabled()) ? label.getIcon() : label.getDisabledIcon();

        if ((icon == null) && (text == null)) {
            return;
        }

        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
        paintViewInsets = c.getInsets(paintViewInsets);

        paintViewR.x = paintViewInsets.left;
        paintViewR.y = paintViewInsets.top;

        // Use inverted height & width
        paintViewR.height = c.getWidth() - (paintViewInsets.left + paintViewInsets.right);
        paintViewR.width = c.getHeight() - (paintViewInsets.top + paintViewInsets.bottom);

        paintIconR.x = paintIconR.y = paintIconR.width = paintIconR.height = 0;
        paintTextR.x = paintTextR.y = paintTextR.width = paintTextR.height = 0;

        String clippedText =
            layoutCL(label, fm, text, icon, paintViewR, paintIconR, paintTextR);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        AffineTransform tr = g2.getTransform();
        if (clockwise) {
            g2.rotate( Math.PI / 2 );
            g2.translate( 0, - c.getWidth() );
        } else {
            g2.rotate( - Math.PI / 2 );
            g2.translate( - c.getHeight(), 0 );
        }

        if (icon != null) {
            icon.paintIcon(c, g, paintIconR.x, paintIconR.y);
        }

        if (text != null) {
            int textX = paintTextR.x;
            int textY = paintTextR.y + fm.getAscent();

            if (label.isEnabled()) {
                paintEnabledText(label, g, clippedText, textX, textY);
            } else {
                paintDisabledText(label, g, clippedText, textX, textY);
            }
        }

        g2.setTransform( tr );
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you put some of the code here that does the job?  Just in case the codeguru thing disappears.

Comment: I don't want to copy code from their site.. I don't think that would be right.  sorry :(

Comment: This will *not* render HTML. To do so, you should add `View v = (View)c.getClientProperty(BasicHTML.propertyKey); if (v != null) { v.paint(g, paintTextR); } else {...` after the `if (text != null) {`. Just as in `BasicLableUI.java#paint()`.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it by messing with the paint command, sort of like this:

```
public class JVertLabel extends JComponent{
  private String text;

  public JVertLabel(String s){
    text = s;
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

    g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(270.0)); 
    g2d.drawString(text, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: i changed extends JComponent to extends JLabel .but JVertLabel texts are  still not displayed vertically.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to show text in a JLabel vertically is to use HTML tags in the text of the JLabel.  For example  `setText("<HTML>H<br>E<br>L<br>L<br>O</HTML>");` will set the text to

H
E
L
L
O

Comment: This does funny things, for me it makes the width of the `JLabel` take up the maximum size possible

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the SwingX API

Bottom to top :

```
JXLabel label = new JXLabel("MY TEXT");
label.setTextRotation(3 * Math.PI / 2);
```

Top to bottom :

```
JXLabel label = new JXLabel("MY TEXT");
label.setTextRotation(Math.PI / 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution that:

- Considers localisation
- Can draw characters either stacked vertically & centred, or rotated

http://www.macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2002/03/22/vertical_text.html

Highlighting a note in the Javadoc:

> Chinese/Japanese/Korean scripts have special rules when 
>   drawn vertically and should never be rotated

See the article for some visual examples.

Here's the main class [JTextIcon.java](http://www.macdevcenter.com/mac/2002/03/22/examples/VTextIcon.java), in case the article drops off the web:

```
/**
 VTextIcon is an Icon implementation which draws a short string vertically.
 It's useful for JTabbedPanes with LEFT or RIGHT tabs but can be used in any
 component which supports Icons, such as JLabel or JButton 

 You can provide a hint to indicate whether to rotate the string 
 to the left or right, or not at all, and it checks to make sure 
 that the rotation is legal for the given string 
 (for example, Chinese/Japanese/Korean scripts have special rules when 
 drawn vertically and should never be rotated)
 */
public class VTextIcon implements Icon, PropertyChangeListener {
    String fLabel;
    String[] fCharStrings; // for efficiency, break the fLabel into one-char strings to be passed to drawString
    int[] fCharWidths; // Roman characters should be centered when not rotated (Japanese fonts are monospaced)
    int[] fPosition; // Japanese half-height characters need to be shifted when drawn vertically
    int fWidth, fHeight, fCharHeight, fDescent; // Cached for speed
    int fRotation;
    Component fComponent;

    static final int POSITION_NORMAL = 0;
    static final int POSITION_TOP_RIGHT = 1;
    static final int POSITION_FAR_TOP_RIGHT = 2;

    public static final int ROTATE_DEFAULT = 0x00;
    public static final int ROTATE_NONE = 0x01;
    public static final int ROTATE_LEFT = 0x02;
    public static final int ROTATE_RIGHT = 0x04;

    /**
     * Creates a <code>VTextIcon</code> for the specified <code>component</code>
     * with the specified <code>label</code>.
     * It sets the orientation to the default for the string
     * @see #verifyRotation
     */
    public VTextIcon(Component component, String label) {
        this(component, label, ROTATE_DEFAULT);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a <code>VTextIcon</code> for the specified <code>component</code>
     * with the specified <code>label</code>.
     * It sets the orientation to the provided value if it's legal for the string
     * @see #verifyRotation
     */
    public VTextIcon(Component component, String label, int rotateHint) {
        fComponent = component;
        fLabel = label;
        fRotation = verifyRotation(label, rotateHint);
        calcDimensions();
        fComponent.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * sets the label to the given string, updating the orientation as needed
     * and invalidating the layout if the size changes
     * @see #verifyRotation
     */
    public void setLabel(String label) {
        fLabel = label;
        fRotation = verifyRotation(label, fRotation); // Make sure the current rotation is still legal
        recalcDimensions();
    }

    /**
     * Checks for changes to the font on the fComponent
     * so that it can invalidate the layout if the size changes
     */
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
        String prop = e.getPropertyName();
        if("font".equals(prop)) {
            recalcDimensions();
        }
    }

    /** 
     * Calculates the dimensions.  If they've changed,
     * invalidates the component
     */
    void recalcDimensions() {
        int wOld = getIconWidth();
        int hOld = getIconHeight();
        calcDimensions();
        if (wOld != getIconWidth() || hOld != getIconHeight())
            fComponent.invalidate();
    }

    void calcDimensions() {
        FontMetrics fm = fComponent.getFontMetrics(fComponent.getFont());
        fCharHeight = fm.getAscent() + fm.getDescent();
        fDescent = fm.getDescent();
        if (fRotation == ROTATE_NONE) {
            int len = fLabel.length();
            char data[] = new char[len];
            fLabel.getChars(0, len, data, 0);
            // if not rotated, width is that of the widest char in the string
            fWidth = 0;
            // we need an array of one-char strings for drawString
            fCharStrings = new String[len];
            fCharWidths = new int[len];
            fPosition = new int[len];
            char ch;
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                ch = data[i];
                fCharWidths[i] = fm.charWidth(ch);
                if (fCharWidths[i] > fWidth)
                    fWidth = fCharWidths[i];
                fCharStrings[i] = new String(data, i, 1);               
                // small kana and punctuation
                if (sDrawsInTopRight.indexOf(ch) >= 0) // if ch is in sDrawsInTopRight
                    fPosition[i] = POSITION_TOP_RIGHT;
                else if (sDrawsInFarTopRight.indexOf(ch) >= 0)
                    fPosition[i] = POSITION_FAR_TOP_RIGHT;
                else
                    fPosition[i] = POSITION_NORMAL;
            }
            // and height is the font height * the char count, + one extra leading at the bottom
            fHeight = fCharHeight * len + fDescent;
        }       
        else {
            // if rotated, width is the height of the string
            fWidth = fCharHeight;
            // and height is the width, plus some buffer space 
            fHeight = fm.stringWidth(fLabel) + 2*kBufferSpace;
        }
    }

   /**
     * Draw the icon at the specified location.  Icon implementations
     * may use the Component argument to get properties useful for 
     * painting, e.g. the foreground or background color.
     */
    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        // We don't insist that it be on the same Component
        g.setColor(c.getForeground());
        g.setFont(c.getFont());
        if (fRotation == ROTATE_NONE) {
            int yPos = y + fCharHeight;
            for (int i = 0; i < fCharStrings.length; i++) {
                // Special rules for Japanese - "half-height" characters (like ya, yu, yo in combinations)
                // should draw in the top-right quadrant when drawn vertically
                // - they draw in the bottom-left normally
                int tweak;
                switch (fPosition[i]) {
                    case POSITION_NORMAL: 
                        // Roman fonts should be centered. Japanese fonts are always monospaced.  
                        g.drawString(fCharStrings[i], x+((fWidth-fCharWidths[i])/2), yPos);
                        break;
                    case POSITION_TOP_RIGHT:
                        tweak = fCharHeight/3; // Should be 2, but they aren't actually half-height
                        g.drawString(fCharStrings[i], x+(tweak/2), yPos-tweak); 
                        break;
                    case POSITION_FAR_TOP_RIGHT:
                        tweak = fCharHeight - fCharHeight/3;
                        g.drawString(fCharStrings[i], x+(tweak/2), yPos-tweak); 
                        break;
                }
                yPos += fCharHeight;
            }
        }
        else if (fRotation == ROTATE_LEFT) {
            g.translate(x+fWidth,y+fHeight);
            ((Graphics2D)g).rotate(-NINETY_DEGREES);
            g.drawString(fLabel, kBufferSpace, -fDescent);
            ((Graphics2D)g).rotate(NINETY_DEGREES);
            g.translate(-(x+fWidth),-(y+fHeight));
        } 
        else if (fRotation == ROTATE_RIGHT) {
            g.translate(x,y);
            ((Graphics2D)g).rotate(NINETY_DEGREES);
            g.drawString(fLabel, kBufferSpace, -fDescent);
            ((Graphics2D)g).rotate(-NINETY_DEGREES);
            g.translate(-x,-y);
        } 

    }

    /**
     * Returns the icon's width.
     *
     * @return an int specifying the fixed width of the icon.
     */
    public int getIconWidth() {
        return fWidth;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the icon's height.
     *
     * @return an int specifying the fixed height of the icon.
     */
    public int getIconHeight() {
        return fHeight;
    }

    /** 
         verifyRotation

        returns the best rotation for the string (ROTATE_NONE, ROTATE_LEFT, ROTATE_RIGHT)

        This is public static so you can use it to test a string without creating a VTextIcon

     from http://www.unicode.org/unicode/reports/tr9/tr9-3.html
     When setting text using the Arabic script in vertical lines, 
     it is more common to employ a horizontal baseline that 
     is rotated by 90� counterclockwise so that the characters 
     are ordered from top to bottom. Latin text and numbers 
     may be rotated 90� clockwise so that the characters 
     are also ordered from top to bottom.

        Rotation rules
        - Roman can rotate left, right, or none - default right (counterclockwise)
        - CJK can't rotate
        - Arabic must rotate - default left (clockwise)

     from the online edition of _The Unicode Standard, Version 3.0_, file ch10.pdf page 4
     Ideographs are found in three blocks of the Unicode Standard...
     U+4E00-U+9FFF, U+3400-U+4DFF, U+F900-U+FAFF

     Hiragana is U+3040-U+309F, katakana is U+30A0-U+30FF

     from http://www.unicode.org/unicode/faq/writingdirections.html
     East Asian scripts are frequently written in vertical lines 
     which run from top-to-bottom and are arrange columns either 
     from left-to-right (Mongolian) or right-to-left (other scripts). 
     Most characters use the same shape and orientation when displayed 
     horizontally or vertically, but many punctuation characters 
     will change their shape when displayed vertically.

     Letters and words from other scripts are generally rotated through 
     ninety degree angles so that they, too, will read from top to bottom. 
     That is, letters from left-to-right scripts will be rotated clockwise 
     and letters from right-to-left scripts counterclockwise, both 
     through ninety degree angles.

    Unlike the bidirectional case, the choice of vertical layout 
    is usually treated as a formatting style; therefore, 
    the Unicode Standard does not define default rendering behavior 
    for vertical text nor provide directionality controls designed to override such behavior

     */
    public static int verifyRotation(String label, int rotateHint) {
        boolean hasCJK = false;
        boolean hasMustRotate = false; // Arabic, etc

        int len = label.length();
        char data[] = new char[len];
        char ch;
        label.getChars(0, len, data, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            ch = data[i];
            if ((ch >= '\u4E00' && ch <= '\u9FFF') ||
                (ch >= '\u3400' && ch <= '\u4DFF') ||
                (ch >= '\uF900' && ch <= '\uFAFF') ||
                (ch >= '\u3040' && ch <= '\u309F') ||
                (ch >= '\u30A0' && ch <= '\u30FF') )
               hasCJK = true;
            if ((ch >= '\u0590' && ch <= '\u05FF') || // Hebrew
                (ch >= '\u0600' && ch <= '\u06FF') || // Arabic
                (ch >= '\u0700' && ch <= '\u074F') ) // Syriac
               hasMustRotate = true;
        }
        // If you mix Arabic with Chinese, you're on your own
        if (hasCJK)
            return DEFAULT_CJK;

        int legal = hasMustRotate ? LEGAL_MUST_ROTATE : LEGAL_ROMAN;
        if ((rotateHint & legal) > 0)
            return rotateHint;

        // The hint wasn't legal, or it was zero
        return hasMustRotate ? DEFAULT_MUST_ROTATE : DEFAULT_ROMAN;
    }

    // The small kana characters and Japanese punctuation that draw in the top right quadrant:
    // small a, i, u, e, o, tsu, ya, yu, yo, wa  (katakana only) ka ke
    static final String sDrawsInTopRight = 
        "\u3041\u3043\u3045\u3047\u3049\u3063\u3083\u3085\u3087\u308E" + // hiragana 
        "\u30A1\u30A3\u30A5\u30A7\u30A9\u30C3\u30E3\u30E5\u30E7\u30EE\u30F5\u30F6"; // katakana
    static final String sDrawsInFarTopRight = "\u3001\u3002"; // comma, full stop

    static final int DEFAULT_CJK = ROTATE_NONE;
    static final int LEGAL_ROMAN = ROTATE_NONE | ROTATE_LEFT | ROTATE_RIGHT;
    static final int DEFAULT_ROMAN = ROTATE_RIGHT; 
    static final int LEGAL_MUST_ROTATE = ROTATE_LEFT | ROTATE_RIGHT;
    static final int DEFAULT_MUST_ROTATE = ROTATE_LEFT;

    static final double NINETY_DEGREES = Math.toRadians(90.0);
    static final int kBufferSpace = 5;
}
```

Provided as free to use for any purpose.

There's also a `CompositeIcon` class that lets you compose the vertical text with another icon (not given here)

As per a comment in the article, add anti-aliasing in the `paintIcon` method:

```
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```