# java how to make a JLabel with vertical text?

Tags: java, jlabel

i need to make a vertical `JLabel`- a `JLabel` which shows it's text vertically- i searched google but i didn't find a good answer. how to do that?

[image]

Comment: please also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92781/how-do-i-present-text-vertically-in-a-jlabel-java-1-6

Comment: @Zhedar the link which is said there has been expired and neither of answers work

Comment: the 2nd answer (not accepted) gives another short explanation about the paint-approach.

Comment: @Zhedar but doesn't work...:(

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6333584/584862) is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the class VerticalLabelUI created by a dev: <s>http://tech.chitgoks.com/2009/11/13/rotate-jlabel-vertically/</s> (dead link now thanks MadMike for the archive link)

```
JLabel jl = new JLabel("TEST");
jl.setUI(new VerticalLabelUI(true));
```

The VerticalLabelUI class

```
public class VerticalLabelUI extends BasicLabelUI {

    static {
        labelUI = new VerticalLabelUI(false);
    }

    protected boolean clockwise;

    public VerticalLabelUI(boolean clockwise) {
        super();
        this.clockwise = clockwise;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(JComponent c) {
        Dimension dim = super.getPreferredSize(c);
        return new Dimension( dim.height, dim.width );
    }

    private static Rectangle paintIconR = new Rectangle();
    private static Rectangle paintTextR = new Rectangle();
    private static Rectangle paintViewR = new Rectangle();
    private static Insets paintViewInsets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        JLabel label = (JLabel)c;
        String text = label.getText();
        Icon icon = (label.isEnabled()) ? label.getIcon() : label.getDisabledIcon();

        if ((icon == null) &amp;&amp; (text == null)) {
            return;
        }

        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
        paintViewInsets = c.getInsets(paintViewInsets);

        paintViewR.x = paintViewInsets.left;
        paintViewR.y = paintViewInsets.top;

        // Use inverted height &amp; width
        paintViewR.height = c.getWidth() - (paintViewInsets.left + paintViewInsets.right);
        paintViewR.width = c.getHeight() - (paintViewInsets.top + paintViewInsets.bottom);

        paintIconR.x = paintIconR.y = paintIconR.width = paintIconR.height = 0;
        paintTextR.x = paintTextR.y = paintTextR.width = paintTextR.height = 0;

        String clippedText = layoutCL(label, fm, text, icon, paintViewR, paintIconR, paintTextR);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        AffineTransform tr = g2.getTransform();
        if (clockwise) {
            g2.rotate( Math.PI / 2 );
            g2.translate( 0, - c.getWidth() );
        } else {
            g2.rotate( - Math.PI / 2 );
            g2.translate( - c.getHeight(), 0 );
        }

        if (icon != null) {
            icon.paintIcon(c, g, paintIconR.x, paintIconR.y);
        }

        if (text != null) {
            int textX = paintTextR.x;
            int textY = paintTextR.y + fm.getAscent();

            if (label.isEnabled()) {
                paintEnabledText(label, g, clippedText, textX, textY);
            } else {
                paintDisabledText(label, g, clippedText, textX, textY);
            }
        }
    g2.setTransform( tr );
    }

}
```

Comment: The linked webpage is gone. Fortunately there is the [web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org) which has a copy of it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190511215129/http://tech.chitgoks.com/2009/11/13/rotate-jlabel-vertically/)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method that will transform your text into an `HTML` code like this:

```
public static String transformStringToHtml(String strToTransform) {
    String ans = "<html>";
    String br = "<br>";
    String[] lettersArr = strToTransform.split("");
    for (String letter : lettersArr) {
        ans += letter + br;
    }
    ans += "</html>";
    return ans;
}
```

Afterwards, if you'll use this method in a `setText` method like this: `someLabel.setText(transformStringToHtml(someString));` where `someString = "Test"` you will receive:

```
T
e
s
t
```

in your label.

Comment: This isn't what OP is looking for.

Comment: @AlexWien Care to explain why?

Comment: I have not downvoted, but: the OP aksed for a rotated text, not for letters unrotation below each other.

Comment: @AlexWien I didn't accuse you for down voting. But you are right, the answer that was accepted answers the question correctly. Other than that, this solution is pretty quick and not complicated.

Comment: I event don't like the accepted answer, I would have done it with a custom view and an transformation matrix. Probaly this exaclty is what the external lib makes, but I avoid external libs if they havent a big benefit.

Comment: @AlexWien so why don't you share us your idea to solve this problem ?

Comment: @Michael -1 not related to what i asked...