# Vertical JLabel Alignment

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, rotatetransform

I was looking for a way to rotate `JLabel` vertically and I found that several posts related to this topic suggest to use `Graphics2d`. But, in this way, the size of my `JLabel` is inconsistent (widht & height inverted).

[image]

I found also that another user, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777926/java-how-to-make-a-jlabel-with-vertical-text), suggested this [code](http://tech.chitgoks.com/2009/11/13/rotate-jlabel-vertically/).
Actually, the code works, but there are no indications about how to align the text of the `JLabel`, and this is what i get:

[image]

Can anyone help with any of the two methods (controlling size in method one or 1 aligning text in method 2)?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create an `Icon` of the text and rotate the Icon then add the Icon to the label. Then the size of the label will be calculated normally.

Check out the [Rotated Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/rotated-icon/) class for an example of this approach. You will also need the `TextIcon` class.

These two classes may seem like extra work, but it is an example of how to create reusable classes to you don't do custom painting all the time.